# How do I create a property in a panel to edit particle systems?

Tags: scripting, modifiers

I have been trying to create a panel that has a particle system's modifiers, but I do not know how to call the particle system in the panel and I do not know how to get the properties. I tried following the answer on [Modifiers: add and set "live" parameters then apply via python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18702/modifiers-add-and-set-live-parameters-then-apply-via-python/18714#18714).

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text = "Basic", icon = 'WORLD_DATA')

    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj.modifiers['Particles'], "count")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
particles = obj.modifiers.get("ParticleSystem 1")
if particles:
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(particles.particle_system.settings, "count")
```

or

```
particles = obj.particle_systems.get('ParticleSystem')
if particles:
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(particles.settings, "count")
```

Comment: I tried it out but the row won't appear.

Comment: then you aren't passing it the right names. In console do  `obj.modifiers[:]` and `obj.particle_systems[:]`  to get the lists..