# Is there a quick way to set the origin to the "bottom centre"?

Tags: modeling, origin

From my experience, it seems that a lot of times when I scaling an object, I would want the bottom of the object stays as it is. For example, think about scaling a lamp on a desk. If I scale the lamp, I would want the lamp to stay on the desk, not going below the desk.

I know the origin decides that, so the origin needs to be at the bottom centre (that is, centre in the X and Y axes, but the lowest in the Z axis). But in the Object -> Set Origin, there is only "Origin to Centre of Mass". I have searched Google and found ways like selecting the bottom face, move the cursor there and then setting origin there, but that seems cumbersome, especially if I have to do it over and over again. Isn't there an easier way? Like "Origin to Bottom Centre of Mass" menu?

Comment: It does exist. And if it didn't it would be easy to make with Python as well.

Comment: Relalted https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18702/modifiers-add-and-set-live-parameters-then-apply-via-python   Sets the origin to bottom when adding primitive.

Comment: @batFINGER, this seems to me to be a different question even though the answer is the same. I think too many questions get closed as duplicates just because they have the same answer even when they are not the same questions. I also think this one is worded very well for other people to find. It seems likely someone would just enter the exact title into some web search engine so maybe it's worth to leave questions like that open.

Comment: Am aware of the duplicate answer vs duplicate question argument. In this case AFAIC it's a dupe.  _"Set origin to bottom centre"_   Hypothetical questions:  Set origin to bottom centre of single object, or Slowest way to set origin to bottom centre would also IMO be dupes.

Comment: @batFINGER So, this is why you knew. Anyway, I added some metadata to your code to make it an add-on. https://pastebin.com/DdrCpJCJ People who would search for this in the future could just download the Python file and add it as an add-on in Preferences -> Add-Ons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable viewport pie menu addon from the preferences(Edit -> Preferences or  F4 -> p):

[image]

Ctrl + Alt + X will call a pie menu with an option:

[image]

Comment: Also see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects) for more solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I also packaged batFINGER's code as an add-on, if anyone is interested. https://pastebin.com/DdrCpJCJ It adds "Bottom Centre" to the "Set Origin" menu. One can save the Python file and add it as an add-on in Preferences->Add-Ons.

Comment: Still works in 2022 (Blender 2.91), thank you so much! I'm surprised this isn't enabled by default. Btw, this also adds a menu to the "ctrl + s" shortcut ("new", "open file", "save", "save as",...).

Comment: 2.91 was released on November 25, 2020 so... so much for 2022... It's an extremely outdated version you are using. But this does work in the real 2022 versions as well.