# If two objects have the same x,y,z position values why are they not in the same exact positon in 3D?

Tags: axis

I have 2 cubes, one cube is 1x1x1 meters and the other is 2x2x2, how can I make the object position relative to the bottom face and not to the center of the cube

so they both be in (0,0,0) at there bottom face touch touch

and Can I make it the default?

I want the objects to start from 0,0,0 - their left bottom point should touch the axis origin

[image]

Comment: Put both their origin at their bottom face and copy the location?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182044/is-there-a-quick-way-to-set-the-origin-to-the-bottom-centre https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects

Comment: thanks, but I want them to all of them to start from the bottom left point

Comment: Well, put the origin at the bottom left corner then?

Comment: yes, but I wanna know if there is a better way than doing it manually each time